# Error cart message on Ajax

Tags: magento2, jquery, widget

*My goal is to have a cart that live updates when you change the quantity's. Normally you need to press the 'update cart' button.*

**So I update my cart live by doing this:**

```
require(['jquery', 'Magento_Customer/js/customer-data',
    'jquery/jquery-storageapi'], function ($) {
    // $("#submitbutton").hide();
    var form = $('form#form-validate');
    var qtyfields = $('input.qty');
    var increase = $('.meigee-arrow-right');
    var decrease = $('.meigee-arrow-left');
    increase.remove();
    decrease.remove();

    form.find(qtyfields).each(function (e) {


        $(this).change(function () {

            console.log('change detected');
            var thisfield = $(this);
            var datafield = thisfield.val();
            thisfield.attr('defaultValue', 'value');
            thisfield.html(datafield);
            TriggerAjax();


        });
    });

    function TriggerAjax() {
        $.ajax({
            url: form.attr('action'),
            data: form.serialize(),
            type: 'post',
            success: function (res) {
                form.submit();
                console.log('succes');
            },
            error: function () {
                console.log('error');
            }
        });
    }

    form.on('submit', function (e) {
        console.log('form submitted');
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function LiveError() {
        console.log('test live error');
    }
});
```

And this works fine. I see the numbers change in my cart when the stock is there. The only thing is that the error message is not visible until I reload my cart page (the checkout/cart page).

**Now i noticed that the form ha**s `data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'`

```
<form action="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $block->getUrl('checkout/cart/updatePost') ?>"
          method="post"
          id="form-validate"
          data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'
          class="form form-cart">
```

When I look closer at that Magento widget it does some kind of validation and sends it through ajax (i guess).

*What I'm thinking is that it's not getting trigger until the page is reloaded so I'm not sure how to initiate this or make this happen.*

**Thanks in advance!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried your code and Ajax run fine but i cannot see the changes at same time. I see changes only when a page is loaded. Regarding message not showing, in my case when ajax request is going on this url:-
http://XXX/Magento2.1.6/checkout/cart/updatePost/
then it throws 302 error because updatePost execute method returns $this->_goBack().
Since we are using ajax we can modify this to return a JSON so that request is updated successfully.
For example, I modified it as

```
 public function execute()
{
    if (!$this->_formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
        return $this->resultRedirectFactory->create()->setPath('*/*/');
    }

    $updateAction = (string)$this->getRequest()->getParam('update_cart_action');

    switch ($updateAction) {
        case 'empty_cart':
            $this->_emptyShoppingCart();
            break;
        case 'update_qty':
            $this->_updateShoppingCart();
            break;
        default:
            $this->_updateShoppingCart();
    }

    echo 55; exit();/* can be anything which server correct ajax response*/
}
```

And it works and shows me error message though my price and other data are currently not updating(Might be this could be the reason):-
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment. So you just changed the updatePost execute? Did you do this with a Plugin (think not since those have before/after/around) or did you do this in another way and how exactly?

Comment: This seems to work and i will comform this as an answer  when i have replaced the controller and see if it still works. An important question -> Why the echo 55?

Comment: I did not use plugin i just do this to show u the solution, you can make changes according to your convenience but for me the reason was incorrect ajax response.

Comment: Ok i replaced the controller by adding a di.xml in etc/frontend with "    <preference for="Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\UpdatePost" type="Designit\LiveUpdate\Controller\Cart\UpdatePost"/>
" and changed what you did to that controller (if anyone wonders). It does seem to work fine now so i will add your response as a answer! Thanks! Just need to know what the echo 55 still is.

Comment: Ok nvm , the 55 i replaced with :       $dataCart = $this->cart->getQuote()->getData();

        echo json_encode($dataCart);
        exit();  and then i can JSON.parse what i want

Comment: Facing this issue I have override the updatePost then also same issue

Answer (score 1):

As error messages are already set to page messages from class "Magento\Checkout\Controller\Cart\UpdatePost::_updateShoppingCart()" catch part, you can get it in ajax success by using below code

```
var messages = $.cookieStorage.get('mage-messages');
if (!_.isEmpty(messages)) {
    customerData.set('messages', {messages: messages});
    $.cookieStorage.set('mage-messages', '');
}

//reload messages section
var messages_section = ['messages'];
//customerData.invalidate(messages_sections);
customerData.reload(messages_section);
```